# Is it possible to run mvn sonar:sonar for maven project in other application?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I am able to add my maven java web project(say example:ApplicationBuild) to sonar running on my local machine. Now I  want to write a small new java application which should add "Application Build" to sonar instead adding same from command line using mvn sonar:sonar. Is it possible? I searched but i din't get solution for this.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me : you want to run mvn sonar:sonar on some machine and have the result displayed in a Sonar instance running on another machine ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? It's not very clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I mean is it possible to execute mvn sonar:sonar for specific project through java program?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

it check whether your local sonar instance is localhost:9000/

Comment: wow that's really interesting. my machine sonar running on port 9000 only. can u give me some sample example program or some related stuff, from where i can get idea.

Comment: @user2215139 just run "mvn sonar:sonar". This will use all the Sonar defaults to perform analysis on your Maven project's code. If your Sonar server is located on another server then you'll need to set various Sonar properties. This approach means possible to run Sonar using little or no customisation of your Maven project.

Comment: @user2215139 this will helpful you to test your mvn sonar:sonar command https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/ut/maven/ut-maven-jacoco-runTests